# Unable to catch SocketTimeoutExeption

Tags: java, sockets, socket-timeout-exception

I am attempting to catch a SocketTimeoutException so that my socket remains active and I can continue reading through my program. Unfortunately, no matter how I attempt to catch the read timeout I can't and therefore the application closes.

I have a socket and setsotimeout to 30000.

I call input.readLine() and want to catch the timeout and continue.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
String response;
try {
        response = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server Response: " + response);
        return;
} catch(AssertionError e){
    //we timed out. print to user that timeout occured,
    //try command again
    System.out.println("TIMEOUT: Please try your command again.\n"
        + "If you created a game, join an existing or create again.");
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    //we timed out. print to user that timeout occured,
    //try command again
    System.out.println("TIMEOUT: Please try your command again.\n"
        + "If you created a game, join an existing or create again.");
} catch (IOException ex) {
//do nothing
}
```

the output is:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at Client.main(Client.java:97)
```

Comment: what is in Client.java:97?

Comment: It is  the input.readLine() call. I don't mind the timeout.... I am purposely wanting a timeout after 30 seconds. But I don't want my application to stop because of it. I want to catch that timeout and just continue on my way.

Comment: Ah actually, its a different readLine(). Thanks for your help. I didn't have the socketException in the right catch block. That'll be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Either this isn't the real code, you have your own SocketTimeoutException class somewhere, or you've imported the wrong one. I suggest you put something useful into the catch IOException block. You might get a surprise.

Why you're catching AssertionError and treating it as a timeout is a mystery to me.

Comment: I originally was just catching SocketException, however I read online about some Assertionerror and threw it in as a what the heck. At this point, I'm completely baffled as to why i can't catch the timeout.